# Creating a tick system with BC date

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code currently works via after each tick, add 1 to the date, you can see that this then dependant on the month etc will add a month/year when necessary. This is more visual than anything as all game logic will be using the total days system.

However, as you can see there are a multitude of different issues, ie all months are 30 days, and this is alot of code as opposed to a simple DateTime method. However my game is set in 1000 BC and so I cant use the DateTime format. How can I get around this issue?

```
public Text timeText;

public byte day = 1;
public byte month = 1;
public short year = 1000;

public int totalYears = 1;
public int totalMonths = 1;
public int totalDays = 1;

[Range(0.1f, 5f)]
public float timeSpeed = 1f;
private float elapsedTime = 0;

public bool play = true;

private string[] monthNames = new string[13]
{
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
    "January"
};


private void Update()
{
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (elapsedTime >= timeSpeed)
    {
        elapsedTime = 0f;

        AddDay();
        Debug.Log(day + ", " + monthNames[(int)month] + ", " + year.ToString() + " BC");
    }
}

private void AddDay()
{
    totalDays += 1;
    day += 1;

    if (day == 31)
    {
        day = 1;
        AddMonth();
    }
}

private void AddMonth()
{
    totalMonths += 1;
    month += 1;

    if (month == 13)
    {
        month = 1;
        AddYear();
    }
}

private void AddYear()
{
    year -= 1;
    totalYears += 1;
}

public void updateTimeText()
{
    timeText.text = monthNames[(int)month] + ", " + year.ToString() + " BC";
}
```

**EDIT:** I was potentially looking to design my own calendar using the following;

```
public class GameCalendar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Month> months = new List<Month>();

    public void Awake()
    {
        AddMonth(1, "January", 31);
        AddMonth(2, "February", 28);
        AddMonth(3, "March", 31);
        AddMonth(4, "April", 30);
        AddMonth(5, "May", 31);
        AddMonth(6, "June", 30);
        AddMonth(7, "July", 31);
        AddMonth(8, "August", 31);
        AddMonth(9, "September", 30);
        AddMonth(10, "October", 31);
        AddMonth(11, "November", 30);
        AddMonth(12, "December", 31);
    }

    public void AddMonth(byte _monthInt, string _monthName, byte _daysInMonth)
    {
        Month m = new Month();
        m.monthInt = _monthInt;
        m.monthName = _monthName;
        m.daysInMonth = _daysInMonth;
        months.Add(m);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Month
{
    public byte monthInt;
    public string monthName;
    public byte daysInMonth;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me [what problem you are trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Note that January, February et al. didn't exist in 1000BC either. Are you trying to create a [proleptic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)?

Comment: Thank you for your time, and apologies if I was unclear. The question I am asking is similar to how the date/time variables work by holding an int value can be called by a method to convert it into a string dd/mm/yyyy. How can I achieve a similar outcome as opposed to each tick adding a day and a month and a year. How can I just reference the int value of totalDays and convert that to dd/mm/yyyy whilst also taking into consideration the month it is in, so that all months are not initialised to be 30 days.

Comment: So a use case for a discussed above is when an ingame event happens, the event class will store the int of the currentday and the dateOfEvent. Then in the UI similarly as how you would call a TimeDate.ToString() method I could do the same with my dateOfEvent variable

Comment: Sounds like you should be making your own date class.

Comment: @BugFinder I thought that this would be case. I am working on it at the moment, just wish there was a simpler work around. Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nodatime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) which supports historic dates and different calendars.